# Converting any date format in MM/DD/YYYY format

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, datetime

I am having difficulty with different date formats. I am having a web application created using `asp.net` `c#`. I have used `JQuery` Calendar control which shows date along-with time.

I am then parsing this date using `DateTime.Parse()`. If the server is set with indian date format then the application generates conversion error ***"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."***

Is there a way to convert any date format into `MM/DD/YYYY` format along with time?
I know i can use `DateTime.ParseExact()` but again it will stuck with a particular format.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks for sharing you wisdom.

Comment: And what is this format that you are having problems with? Should we be guessing? Please also post your parsing code.

Comment: @Oded: My system is set with English (India) format in Regional setting (30-04-2012 16:40), where as i am getting 04/30/2012 16:40:10 by the JQuery date format. So i am getting the conversion error while using DateTime.Parse().

Comment: Why are you not using an overload that takes a `IFormatProvider` such as the Indian `CultureInfo` object?

Comment: @Oded: This is for an example. If my client is hosting the application on a server where other that English US format is used then i am unable to convert the date into English format.

Comment: Then why don't you use an appropriate `CultureInfo` to the locale the user is in?

Comment: @Oded: Can you please provide sample example/link for this.

Comment: please find my answer below for CultureInfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:MM:ss");
```

You can replace en-US by hi-IN for Hindi Date or as per you like. please follow link. for Culture Info.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

If you are unsure of Culture then use below line.

```
Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:MM:ss");
```

reference here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx

Other Method you can use is.

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParse(DateTime.Now.ToString(), out dt);
```

Comment: Thanks Kamran. Please read my comments in reply to Oded. I am not stuck with any particular format.

Comment: irfan use try parse and it will try to parse the date from any format. and store it in variable. If you are unsure of culture.

Answer (score 1):

You can try DateTime.Parse or DateTime.TryParse methods

```
   DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");
```

Also refer

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Thanks

Deepu

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
public static CultureInfo CreateCulture(string shortDateFormat)
{

        CultureInfo newCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = shortDateFormat;
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = shortDateFormat;

        return newCulture;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Extension methods for this you need to create a static class with static method. It will return you a date format that you define in class

```
public static class DateExtension
    {
        public static string GetDateTime(this DateTime? date)
        {
            if (date.HasValue)
                return date.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm tt");
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Now in you code you can use this extension for e.g. DateTime.GetDateTime() it will return date with time that with the format you specify in your extension library class

Answer (score 0):

```
string s;  
 s = dt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
Console.WriteLine(s);//Displays 04-30-2012
```